# How do I go about pushing data to a private GitHub repository through the CLI?

Tags: ubuntu, github, command-line-interface, push

As the title explains, how do I go about pushing data to a private GitHub repository through the CLI? I'm using Ubuntu 22.04 LTS.

Comment: Basically ... the same way as you would to push data to a public repo.  And that is the same as you would push *any* information to a remote repo.  Add locally, commit locally, push.   See https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/syncing/git-push for example.

Comment: Managed to resolve it with your solution, thanks! I forgot to actually commit the updates and was just trying to push them.

Comment: How embarrassing :-).   (I suggest you delete this question.)